# Angular UI StateProvider Otherwise options

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

How to user otherwise on stateProvider similar like angular UI router provider otherwise

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
 .config(['$urlRouterProvider','$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider){
  $urlRouterProvider
      .otherwise('/');
   
  $stateProvider
    .state('home',{
     url : '/',
     template: 'path_to_template',
     controller: 'homeCtrl'
     })
 }])
```